# What does "回る" mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

> 公明党が容認に回ることで、両議会での議決が可能となることから、４年前に続いて、２度目の住民投票が行われる見通しとなりました。

Quoted from an [NHK news article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20190511/k10011912861000.html), which might not be accessible weeks after being published.

Or to put my question in another way, how do I translate "容認に回ること" into English properly?

I did some searching of the word "回る" in Japanese dictionaries, but there are so many meanings/usages for different cases that I am not sure which one is applicable in the aforementioned sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's definition 7 from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210283/meaning/m0u/%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B/) (highlighting mine)

> ７ それまでとは異なった立場に**変わる**。「賛成に―・る」「受け身に―・る」

That is to say that the 公明党 did not originally approve of the referendum. But because their position **changed** to approving the referendum, there are now enough votes in the 両議会 to do the referendum.